# How to sort values of keys?

Tags: javascript

from api i get this strings:
"18% increased Area of Effect", "25% increased Area of Effect", "19% increased Area of Effect"

i want to make like this:
"(18%-25%) increased Area of Effect"

```
 const filtredArray = array.filter((item) => item.implicit_mods);
 let implicitsList = [];

 filtredArray.forEach((item) => implicitsList.push(item.implicit_mods));

 implicitsList.forEach((implisit) => {
   if (implisit) {
     implisit.forEach((implicit) => {
       if (implicit) {
         if (!/\d/.test(implicit)) {
           //implicits without number
           if (!uniqueImplicitMap.get(implicit)) {
             addToMap(uniqueImplicitMap, implicit);
           }
         } else {
           // implicits with number
           let value = implicit.match(/\d+/g);
           let replaceImplicit = implicit.replace(/\d+/g, '#');
           if (value.length >= 2) {
             addToMap(uniqueImplicitMap, replaceImplicit, [
               value[0],
               value[1],
             ]);
           } else {
             addToMap(uniqueImplicitMap, replaceImplicit, value);
           }
         }
       }
     });
   }
 });
} 

function addToMap(map, key, value) {
 if (!map.get(key)) {
   if (value) {
     map.set(key, [value, value]);
   } else {
     map.set(key);
   }
 }
 if (map.get(key) && value) {
   if (value[0] > map.get(key)[0]) {
     map.get(key).splice(0, 1, value);
   } else if (value < map.get(key)[0] && value < map.get(key)[1]) {
     map.get(key).splice(1, 1, value);
   }
 }
}
```

i can do it if i have only one number in string
but if string like this:
"10% chance to gain Unholy Might for 3 seconds on Kill"

code break.

help me please

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand your code. What I think you want is if you get a array of strings from the API like `["18% increased Area of Effect", "25% increased Area of Effect", "19% increased Area of Effect"]`, and you want to make that into `(18%-25%) increased Area of Effect`.

If so, you can just run a `.map` onto the array to find the percent with symbols, and get the percent. With that is is quite easy to generate a string with ES6 template literals.

#### Example Code

[JS Fiddle for snippet.](https://jsfiddle.net/sean7777/g8u1qe70/99/)

```js
// Select elements on HTML
const
    before = document.querySelector(".previous"),
    before2 = document.querySelector(".previous2"),
  after = document.querySelector(".after"),
  after2 = document.querySelector(".after2");

// Sample API text
const beforeText = ["18% increased Area of Effect", "25% increased Area of Effect", "19% increased Area of Effect"];
const before2Text = ["10% chance to gain Unholy Might for 3 seconds on Kill", "18% chance to gain Unholy Might for 3 seconds on Kill", "26% chance to gain Unholy Might for 3 seconds on Kill"];

// Display before paresed strings
before.innerText = beforeText.join(" -=- ");
before2.innerText = before2Text.join(" -=- ");

// Display parsed strings
after.innerText = parser(beforeText);
after2.innerText = parser(before2Text);

function parser(arrText) {
    const PERCENT_REGEX = /[0-9]{1,2}%/;
  
  // Get percents of strings.
    const percents = arrText.map(elem => {
    const percentStr = elem.match(PERCENT_REGEX)[0];
    return parseInt(
        // Remove percent symbol
        percentStr.substring(0, percentStr.length - 1), 10
     );
  });
  
  const chanceToDoWhat = arrText[0].replace(PERCENT_REGEX, "");
  return `(${Math.min(...percents)}%-${Math.max(...percents)}%)${chanceToDoWhat}`;
}
```

```html
Before Parse:<br>
<code class="previous"></code>
<br>
<br>
Before Parse 2:<br>
<code class="previous2"></code>
<br>
<br>
After Parse:<br>
<code class="after"></code>
<br>
<br>
After Parse 2:<br>
<code class="after2"></code>
```